# How do I hide only the first element of a parent class

Tags: css

I have the following markup:

```css
.shwonlyclick {
  display: none;
}

.asd>.delfirstdiv:first-child>.shwonlyclick:first-child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="asd">
  <div>title</div>
  <div>sub title</div>
  <div class="delfirstdiv">
    <p class="shwonlyclick">Show this</p>
  </div>
  <div class="delfirstdiv">
    <p class="shwonlyclick">Hide</p>
  </div>
  <div class="delfirstdiv">
    <p class="shwonlyclick">Hide</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

all  tags are hidden, I only want the first one show. How?

Comment: you would have to move them title and subtitle outside the asd div and add display for your second selector to work - you're title is the first child of the parent div so your selector will never work (even if you add display)

Comment: ?? `.delfirstdiv ~.delfirstdiv shwonlyclick {display:none;}` What is the idea , hide/show elements on click, then you need either js, input or tabindex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your title and sub-title outside the parent div and fix your typo in your selector and it will work:

`first-child` is the first element inside it's parent (not the first element with a class name)

```css
.shwonlyclick {
  display: none;
}

.asd>.delfirstdiv:first-child>.shwonlyclick:first-child {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div>title</div>
<div>sub title</div>
<div class="asd">
  <div class="delfirstdiv">
    <p class="shwonlyclick">Show this</p>
  </div>
  <div class="delfirstdiv">
    <p class="shwonlyclick">Hide</p>
  </div>
  <div class="delfirstdiv">
    <p class="shwonlyclick">Hide</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

if you are unable to change the html layout, then you can use the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) to hide any divs that follow another (which will mean the first is shown):

```css
.delfirstdiv+.delfirstdiv .shwonlyclick {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="asd">
  <div>title</div>
  <div>sub title</div>
  <div class="delfirstdiv">
    <p class="shwonlyclick">Show this</p>
  </div>
  <div class="delfirstdiv">
    <p class="shwonlyclick">Hide</p>
  </div>
  <div class="delfirstdiv">
    <p class="shwonlyclick">Hide</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I use the second method `adjacent sibling combinator`